# angular es6, this, scope and el all undefined in jqlite click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I can't get the link function to work in ES6. There is no context passed upon a click event at all - am I missing something obvious?

```
    export function TbeDirective() {
      'ngInject';

      let directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'app/main/directives/template.html',
        controller: TheController,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true,
        link: function(scope, el, attr, vm){

          el.bind('keypress', function(){
            var x = this.firstChild; //in the console this is the element,
                                     //but when the code runs it is undefned
            console.log(this);       //undefined
            console.log(TheDirective);  //undefined
            console.log(el);            //undefined
            console.log(vm);            //undefined
          });
        }
      };

      return directive;
    }

    class TheController {
      constructor ($scope) {
        'ngInject';

      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You're using an arrow function, which doesn't have a context.

Comment: doesnt work without the arrow function either

Comment: If you want `this` to be the element within the event handler then the handler must not be an arrow function. There's also no point in having an arrow function for `link`.

Comment: like I said, it doesnt work either way

Comment: the context works in the console, it doesnt actually work at run time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `TheController` has to be defined above where it is used.

`class`es do not get hoisted that I know of.